# need some help authenticating to github API with python

Tags: python, oauth, flask, github-api, rauth

I have followed [this](http://www.vurt.ru/eng/2013/06/using-flask-and-rauth-for-github-authentication/) tutorial to authenticate to the Github API using Python.

Though, for me it doesn't work, when I go to localhost:5000 I'm getting a "this webpage is not available" message. it just says that it's started at localhost:5000 and returning no errors after I executed `python github.py`. My directory/file tree looks like:

```
-templates
 -login.html
 -about.html
-github.py
-github.db
```

message after executing: `python github.py`

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

What did I do wrong and is there any way I can make this work correctly?

**Or, are there any alternatives on authenticating to the Github API using Python? Couldn't find any, but are there?**

Comment: Or are there any alternatives on authenticating to the Github API using Python. Couldn't find any, but are there?

Comment: [PyGithub](https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub) accepts OAuth2 tokens, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: tutorial link is broken

Comment: https://developer.github.com/libraries/#python

Answer (score 0):

Folder names are case sensitive. You've named your folder `Templates` but Flask is looking for one named `templates`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! But it doesn't fix the issue. do you have more suggestions?

Comment: Not without seeing your actual code. Visiting localhost:5000 with the code provided in the tutorial renders `templates/login.html`.